# How to tell computationally that a volume of points constitutes a manifold

Tags: manifolds

Suppose that a space ${\mathbb R}^{r}$ contains a set of points which we
want to consider as enclosing a volume within the space, or perhaps a volume in
a submanifold (e.g., the sphere $S^{2}$ within 3-space).  How do we detect computationally
that a set of points constitutes a manifold?  Some cases such as regularly spaced
rectangular arrays are easy, but I will be looking at irregularly distributed points,
and they won't necessarily look "nice".
Any literature on this subject?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you taking a random sampling of points in a known submanifold and looking for ways to find out what that submanifold is?

Comment: Strictly speaking, any discrete set of points is contained in some submanifold. In practice one can look for submanifolds that are reasonably simple: defined by equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ where $F$ is  a function in some class. A key term here is *surface fitting*.

Comment: You may also be interested in *random manifolds*.

Comment: See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction#Manifold_learning_algorithms .